# On Button Press The wrong list is expanded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a webpage in which, on there is a list(allitems-list) and a favourites list. The favourites group have names and on clicking a button(+-) it shows the contents of the group.

We can add items from the allitems-list to the existing favourites groups, through a popup which shows the existing favourite groups with a button (basically a copy of the favourites list).

On clicking the button(+-) on the Pop-up the button changes from + to - but the list doesn't expand. Instead in the background the item in the favourite group expands (the plus of the popup does change from + to - in the popup but doesn't in the favourites group even when it is expanded in this case. Both of the buttons call the same JS function (attached below).

Both the HTML are more or less same (only difference is the second popup is inside an additional span class). ID's are the same for both (autogenerated by another function)

Code:

```
openfav function (e) {
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
var id = '#inner' + $(e.currentTarget).attr('id').split("_")[1];
if ($(e.currentTarget).attr('src').indexOf('plus.png') != -1) {
$(id).css('display', 'block');
$(($(e.currentTarget).attr('src', '../images/minus.png');
}
else {
$(id).css('display', 'none');
$(($(e.currentTarget).attr('src', '../images/plus.png');
}
}
```

Edit:
Code file is of the format

```
var activeTestItem = ""; 
define(['jquery', '...','....', 'jqueryUi', '.../../prevreq.html' etc ]) 
/*var declarations*/ 
events: { "click "asdfqwer": "qwersdfg"
... 
... 
click.expand_icon: "openfav",
...
...
},
openfavfunction { 
... 
}
```

HTML Format for fav list

```
<li>
<span class>
<input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox-1" id="xyzfav_12345">
<label class="lbl_style" for"abcfav_12345> </label>
</span>
<img id="fav_12345" class="expand_icon" src="../images/minus.png">
<span class="span_txt" data-antialiasid="xyzfav_12345">Name </span>
<div id="inner12345" style="display: none;">
<ul style="width: 100%;">
<li>
<span style="font;padding">content of the group </span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

HTML Format for fav list in POPUP

```
<li>
<span class>
<input type="checkbox" class="input-checkbox-1" id="xyzfav_12345">
<label class="lbl_style" for"abcfav_12345> </label>
</span>
<span>
<img id="fav_12345" class="expand_icon" src="../images/minus.png">
<span class="span_txt" data-antialiasid="xyzfav_12345">Name </span>
<div id="inner12345" style="display: none;">
<ul style="width: 100%;">
<li>
<span style="font;padding">content of the group </span>
</li>
</ul>
</span>
</div>
```

I guess the `e.currenttarget` is pointing to the wrong source in the current HTML file. Any solutions to make it point to the right one .................

how to change or make a new id `var id = '#inner' + $(e.currentTarget).attr('id').split("_")[1];` to make it point to the right one .

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: How are you calling `openfav`? Where and how are you attaching the event handler?

Comment: openfav is called on MouseClick ```click.expand_icon: "openfav",```.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid JS or HTML syntax. Can you [edit] your question to include the complete code, please?

Comment: Unfortunately can't include the complete code......
It is of the Format :

```

var activeTestItem = "";
define(['jquery', '...','....', 'jqueryUi', '.../../prevreq.html' etc ])

var declarations
events: {
"click "asdfqwer": "qwersdfg"
...
...
click.expand_icon: "openfav",
...
...
},
openfavfunction {
...
}

```

Comment: the + icon changes to - in the popup when clicked but the Hidden field is not expanded.
Instead the Hidden field in the page behind the popup is expanded but the + icon there doesn't change.